# How to do a baseless merge or otherwise take away the need for a baseless merge?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I have created a branched copy of my main production code-base so that I can safely perform development.
This involved creating a Main branch (the parent) and then another branch on the same level for my development called Dev(the child).

I have managed the merge the content from my child branch to my parent branch. 
However, when I try and merge from my parent branch to my non-branched Production code base, I encounter problems.

I have attempted peforming a baseless merge using the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2017 Professional edition.

Do I need to do anything else such as converting my Production Code base to a branch. Then to re-parent the main branch and choose the new Production Code base branch as a parent, and perform the remaining merge that way ?

Is that the best way to accomplish my final merge ?

Answer (score 1):

First, if your Production Code base are still folders not a branch. You should convert them to a branch first.

In TFVC, you could only  **merge to directly related branches**(parent or child). There is no merge relationship between main branch and new Production Code branch in your case . You have to perform a baseless merge through **[tf merge command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/merge-command)**.

```
tf merge /baseless <<source path>> <<target path>> /recursive
```

> ***/baseless***
>
> Performs a merge without a base version. That is, allows the user to
>   merge files and folders that do not have a merge relationship. After a
>   baseless merge, **a merge relationship exists**, and future merges do not
>   have to be baseless.
>
> *Note Baseless merges cannot delete files in the target. You can manually carry over such changes.*

If you want to reparent to other branch, you must set a relation ship between the 2 branches first.

In other words, you still need a baseless merge first. Afraid, we could not take away the need for a baseless merge. As for how to reparent branch in TFVC, you could refer my answer in this link: [TFS reparent to be a grandchild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178330/tfs-reparent-to-be-a-grandchild/42195872#42195872)