# Unshelve throws "No appropriate mapping exists" error then works when I try again

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, unshelve

I am getting the aforementioned error most times I unshelve from Team Explorer > Shelveset Details, but unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264653), I have my workspace set correctly under my Pending Changes window. The weird part is that I am *always* able to unshelve after trying a second time *without changing anything*.

It didn't always do this to me, and it seems to not affect anybody else on my team. I've not messed with any settings that I can think of as being relevant either.

And yes, I've restarted my computer since it started happening.

Another thing it does is deletes all ADD changes upon reconciling after passing a gated check-in build.

Thanks.

Using VS 2015 Update 3 (version 14.0.25431.01) connected to TFS 2015 (version 14.102.25423.0)

Comment: Hi Elaskanator, any update on this issue, have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that opening the shelfset before changing my workspace from pending changes causes the issue. The solution is the change the workspace in pending changes **before** opening the shelfset.

I'd definitely call this a bug in VS since the shelfset viewer does not indicate which workspace it is referencing before unshelving.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description:" it seems to not affect anybody else on my team". The issue should be a client side issue.

First,you could use another TFS account to unshelve Shelvesets on your develop machine. This will narrow down if the issue related your account or not.

Suggest you try to [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/):

***For TFS cache:***

- close all instances of Visual Studio on the client machine,
- manually delete the corresponding Tfs client cache folder, and then
- start Visual Studio

  The corresponding Tfs folders to manually delete are as follows:

  ```
      Tfs 2015: "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache\"
  ```

***For VS cache:***

Delete the contents from the following folders

```
C:\Users\<<Your Alias>>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
C:\Users\<<Your Alias>>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon
```

If above not work, you could also delete the old workspace(back up local changes first), and create a new one. Then test it again, which should do the trick.